# Monte Carlo Tree Search Alternating

Tags: artificial-intelligence, game-ai, monte-carlo-tree-search

Could anybody please clarify how (as I have not found any clear example anywhere) The MCTS algorithm iterates for the second player.

Everything I seem just seems to look like it is playing eg P1 move every time. 
I understand the steps for one agent but I never find anything showing code where P2 places its counter, which surely must happen when growing the tree.

Essentially I would expect:

for each iter:

select node Player1
   expand Player1

select node Player2
   expand player 2

rollout
   backpropogate

next iter

Is this right?? Could anybody please spell out some psuedocode showing that? Either iteratively or recursion i don't mind.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the additional advice, I will take another look with that in mind.

Comment: I am still not sure here. I was thinking the iteration must look like this:

for each iter

 player1 select
 player 1 expand

 player2 select
 player2 expand

 rollout
 backpropogate

next iter

Answer (score 1):

The trick is in backpropagation part, where you update "wins" variable from the point of view of player whose move led into this position.

[Code for MCTS](http://mcts.ai/code/python.html)

Notice under UCT function, specially the comments:

```
 #Backpropagate
    while node != None: # backpropagate from the expanded node and work back to the root node
        node.Update(state.GetResult(node.playerJustMoved)) # state is terminal. Update node with result from POV of node.playerJustMoved
        node = node.parentNode
```

IF you follow the function call, you would realize `visit` variable is always updated; `wins` however, is not.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i will review the code shortly. However i do still not get the selection aspect - I surely must have to alternate between moves available to P1, get that node then repeat everything for player 2 akin to minimax??

Comment: Your code looks very descriptive thanks. I think the difficulty I am having is that in my game each player has a distinct set of moves available, like in chess so I cannot keep (as i have seen) a list of available remaining moves - they are relative to player position also like neighbours, so I must generate them anew after each move.

Comment: About the selection aspect, every node knows it's child nodes keeps wins/visits ration from his perspective, so following same UCB formula is ok.
About second comment, notice every node has a corresponding State associated with it. You are asking for all untried moves from that state, (__init__ of Node), so untried moves attribute Node is of course relative to player position, generated anew after each move.

Comment: The problem i am having is that the node does not know which moves are now not available - it sees a picture of the board before each other's last moves and so forth so the players can end up moving 'on top' of each other, or onto other invalid areas. I really cannot get this 'alternate between players in each state' - Within the MCTS iteration loop